# Axios POST request not working

Tags: reactjs, api, http-post, axios, lumen

I know there are lots of question out there with the same issue, but none of the solutions have worked for me yet.

I have a ReactJS application consuming an API built in Lumen. The API is also consumed by **React Native** and **JQuery AJAX** and works fine on both.

When I try to send a **POST** request with axios from ReactJS, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error on the **OPTIONS** Request.

[image: Response Headers] 
[image: Request Headers]

The axios request is:

```
const body = { username, password };

axios.post(`{$uri}/payment/api/login`, {body})
     .then(res => console.log(res))
     .catch(err => console.log('Login: ', err));
```

At first I thought this was a CORS issue, which would have been strange because my API is being consumed by a static site hosted on AWS S3 with no problems. So my CORS middleware works fine.

Than I tried using fetchAPI to call the API and that works fine. I tried to send a **POST** request to a dummy API *https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users* from axios and it worked fine.

**Edit**

Okay so I just found out that fetchAPI sends data in *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* format which somehow is not subject to pre-flight requests. That should mean that there is an issue with the CORS Middleware.

**CORSMiddleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORSMiddleware
{
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */

   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
      $response = $next($request);
      $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
      $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
      $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   }
}
```

The exact same Middleware is also used in another API build in Lumen and consumed by Vue Front-End which uses **axios**.

**Additional Info**

[image: Console Error]

**GET** Request works fine on my API.

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: I did manage to fix it, but I don't remember exactly how. I think it was an issue with my API though. Nothing from React Native.

Comment: In my case, I had to use ```https://www.example.com``` instead of ```https://example.com```

Comment: [You have to pass your params in a `params` argument to axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947650/axios-get-in-url-works-but-with-second-parameter-as-object-it-doesnt/40953463#40953463)

Answer (score 6):

Problem is most likely with your request headers. try setting Content-Type atleast.

```
let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  }
};
const body = { username, password };

axios.post(`{$uri}/payment/api/login`, body, axiosConfig)
 .then(res => console.log(res))
 .catch(err => console.log('Login: ', err));
```

or set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if you are expecting url encoded data in the server side

Comment: axios sets the content-type to applicatio/json itself, however setting it manually does not help either.

Comment: When I use `x-www-form-urlencoded`, I get the parameters in a JSON string in the $_POST object from PHP

Comment: Adding a 'content-type' header solved my issue when using axios.post()

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and ended up learning more than I wanted to know about CORs. Eventually I started from scratch, recreated the API with all the switches for CORs on I could find and then stripped back the code to this:

```
axios.post(postUrl).then(
  (res) => {
    console.log('Axios:',res);
    console.log('Axios data:',res.data);
  }).catch((err) => { console.log('Axios Error:', err); })
```

Worked like a charm. Headers are required server side, not on my app. I hope that helps you.

Comment: Sorry saas_joel that was a very long time ago. It was a fix then and I posted to give others a lead in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, David, I got to fix my Axios woes to
It's amazing how it protects from XRSF

Answer (score 0):

An OPTIONS request is used before your requests in order to check if you are allowed to perform the request from that domain and what headers can be used. [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

This OPTIONS request is failing because the data and Content-Type are conflicting.

You need to add this header in your request: `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`, and use the `JSON.stringify` function to convert your data:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  data,
  url,
};
axios(options);
```

Or, you can just add this header in your request: `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`.

```
const data = { email, password };
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data,
  url,
};
axios(options);
```

The solution depends on your backend API specification.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was on the server side(Node.js).

I was applying my middle-ware function (which checks whether token is present or not) before applying CORS settings, which led to just OPTIONS calls taking place.

e.g.

1. app.use(verifyToken);
2. require("./startup/cors")(app)

I reversed their order and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this request at larval then you need to remove _method from fromData

```
const formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
formData.delete('_method');
```